# タグの入力欄でもタグの種類が見分けられるようにしてほしい

Tags: バグ, 機能の要求, 完了, デザイン, メタ

スタック・オーバーフロー Meta ではタグの種類が 3 種類あります。

- モデレーター専用タグ
- 必須タグ
- タグ

これは質問一覧や質問ページなどではデザインが異なるため直感的に見分けることが出来ます。

[image: 3つの質問が並んでおり、モデレータ専用タグが赤色、必須タグが濃い灰色、タグは薄い灰色で表現されている。]

しかし、タグ編集や質問作成時のタグ入力ではこのような色分けがされておらず、見分けがつきません。必須タグが含まれていない場合や、モデレータではないのにモデレータ専用タグを使った際にはエラー文が表示されますが、検索時にタグの種類が見分けることが出来れば「エラーが出てから直す」といったひと手間がかからなくなると思います。

[image: 仕様とタグという2つのタグが登録されている。また、現在入力しているタグの候補としていくつかタグが上がっているが、タグの種類は区別がつかない。]

Comment: +1: これ、昔はちゃんと見分けられるようになっていた気がするので、どこかのタイミングでデグレーションしてそうですね……。

Comment: 一応、必須タグは入力欄にフォーカスした時にポップアップで一覧として表示されます。色については多言語サイトでのみ反映されていない気がします。 / 「モデレーター専用タグ」はタグ名を (各言語向けに) 翻訳したのもきっかけとして怪しいですね。

Comment: This is definitely a bug. A similar issue is happening on SO in Russian. It's on our backlog to be addressed in the next few weeks.（これは確かにバグです。同様の問題がロシア語版SOでも起こっています。チーム内のbacklogに追加され、今後数週間で対応する予定です。）

Answer (score 6, accepted):

修正されました！インラインエディタが使用された際、非ASCII文字のタグが適切に表示されるようになりました :
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どこかでまたハイライトが正しく表示されていなければどうぞお知らせください。バグのご連絡どうもありがとうございます！