# 必須タグやモデレーター専用タグにプレビュー画面で装飾が付かない

Tags: バグ, 再現性なし, markdown

`[meta-tag:翻訳]` のように書くと、タグを本文に書くことができます。

例：[翻訳](/questions/tagged/%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3)、[討議](/questions/tagged/%e8%a8%8e%e8%ad%b0)、[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)、[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

ここで必須タグやモデレーター専用タグには濃い灰色や赤色といった装飾がつくのですが、投稿プレビュー画面ではついていないと気付きました。

プレビュー画面のスクリーンショット：

> [image: 「翻訳」「討議」「完了」タグが全て灰色で表示されています。]

一方、英語版の Stack Overflow Meta ではプレビュー画面でも装飾がついています。バグっぽいので修正して欲しいです。

---

To SE Team: I found a bug. On SOja Meta, required tags and moderator-only tags are not properly rendered on the preview (screenshot above), whereas they are properly rendered on MSO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

現在、この問題は再現しないようです。もしかしたら、[タグ入力欄のバグ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3306/3054)と一緒に直ったのかも知れません。

---

#### テスト用テキスト

以下は必要な際に、編集ボタンを押してプレビューを確認するためのテキストです。

#### 通常のタグ

[タグ](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%bf%e3%82%b0)
[デザイン](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%87%e3%82%b6%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3)

##### 必須タグ

[サポート](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b5%e3%83%9d%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88)
[バグ](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0)
[機能の要求](/questions/tagged/%e6%a9%9f%e8%83%bd%e3%81%ae%e8%a6%81%e6%b1%82)
[討議](/questions/tagged/%e8%a8%8e%e8%ad%b0)

##### モデレーター専用タグ

[product-discovery](/questions/tagged/product-discovery)
[よくある質問](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%88%e3%81%8f%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f)
[コミュニティ広告](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%9f%e3%83%a5%e3%83%8b%e3%83%86%e3%82%a3%e5%ba%83%e5%91%8a)
[仕様](/questions/tagged/%e4%bb%95%e6%a7%98)
[再現性なし](/questions/tagged/%e5%86%8d%e7%8f%be%e6%80%a7%e3%81%aa%e3%81%97)
[再現済](/questions/tagged/%e5%86%8d%e7%8f%be%e6%b8%88)
[却下](/questions/tagged/%e5%8d%b4%e4%b8%8b)
[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)
[対応予定](/questions/tagged/%e5%af%be%e5%bf%9c%e4%ba%88%e5%ae%9a)
[延期](/questions/tagged/%e5%bb%b6%e6%9c%9f)
[注目](/questions/tagged/%e6%b3%a8%e7%9b%ae)
[調査中](/questions/tagged/%e8%aa%bf%e6%9f%bb%e4%b8%ad)